# Cefsharp Winforms app shows blank browser

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I have a WinForms based cefsharp app that was working. I updated the NuGet packages for CefSharp (to 75.1.142.0) and now the browser only shows blank on start up. The log file says:

```
[1029/115545.989:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(952)] unable to find resource: 164
[1029/115546.193:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(170)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[1029/115546.210:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1205)] The GPU process has crashed 1 time(s)
```

Is there a way to get more detailed debug info?

Comment: Try update graphic card driver.

Comment: @Hostel - No difference unfortunately

Comment: What graphics card? What OS? What version are you upgrading from? You'll probably have to disable GPU acceleration.

Comment: Its a GeForce GT 640 on Windows 10, updating from CEF 71.0.0.0. GPU acceleration is already disabled.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: OK - Stupid me! Updating the packages doesn't update the files in my custom locations (obviously!). Fix that, and everything is sweet!

I found an answer, but I'm not sure why it should be. I commented out the setting of the paths in the CefSharpSettings (as below) and now it works?

```
private static void LoadForm(string[] args)
{
        // Alternate file locations
        string browser = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"CEFSharp\CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe");
        string locales = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"CEFSharp\locales\");
        string res = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"CEFSharp\");
        string cache = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"CEFSharp\cache\");

        // Initialise CEF
        CefSharpSettings.SubprocessExitIfParentProcessClosed = true;
        CefSharp.CefSharpSettings.LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled = true;
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        settings.CachePath = cache;
        settings.MultiThreadedMessageLoop = true;
        settings.ExternalMessagePump = false;
        settings.RemoteDebuggingPort = 8088;
        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-auto-detect", "true");
        settings.LogFile = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"CEFSharp\Debug.log");
        //settings.BrowserSubprocessPath = browser;
        //settings.LocalesDirPath = locales;
        //settings.ResourcesDirPath = res;
        settings.DisableGpuAcceleration();
        Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: true, browserProcessHandler: null);

        Application.Run(new ImportForm(args));
    }
```

Comment: To avoid this in the future you can set `CefSharpTargetDir` in your project file to have **all** the `CefSharp` files copied to a sub directory. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/75/NuGet/CefSharp.Common.targets#L12